# Relative Ext of Avramov-Martsinkovsky as a derived Hom

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, model-categories, derived-categories

Avramov-Martsinkovsky (http://mathserver.neu.edu/~martsinkovsky/Relative.pdf) have defined an exotic version of Ext between two modules over (for simplicity) Gorenstein rings. The basic idea of their construction in the Gorenstein case is to treat "totally reflexive" modules (=modules of G-dimension zero) as the analogue of projective modules. One then takes suitable left resolutions by these modules to obtain this exotic Ext.

I am wondering whether anyone had formulated a "relative derived category" where these Exts are the Hom groups in the category? As a concrete question:
Positselski has defined exotic versions of derived categories in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.2621.pdf. Are the derived categories studied in Section 3.9 related to the [AM] construction?

Remark: I am aware of "stable module categories," which I gather play the role that I want with "relative Ext" replaced by "Tate cohomology."

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but if your analogy is correct, can you just take the category whose objects are modules and whose maps are maps factoring through a totally reflexive module? Ala the stable module category. Would this make any sense?

Comment: Hi Samantha, I think that in the Gorenstein case, this would give the trivial category. For an analogy, this would be similar to the fact that if R is regular, the stable module category is trivial.

Comment: Oh, this paper might help: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5768.pdf
they construct a triangulated category over gorenstein rings that mimics the usual stable module category; perhaps you have already seen it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a Gorenstein derived category where the Ext groups relative to the Gorenstein projectives can be expressed as Homs in this Gorenstein derived categories.
See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.04587.pdf section 3 (especially corollary 3.3.4) for a nice overview on this and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869310000517 for the original research article.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Are there any results about Problem G (concerning compact generation) on page 53 in the arxiv overview/survey that you sent?